# Adding link class on href using jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I researched quite a bit on onClick changes for links but couldn't quite figure out the solution I need. I have a side bar menu that contains multiple links. I have a default class added to the content I want to appear as default. However when I click another link in the sidebar, I want the previous link's "cur" class to be removed, replaced with nothing, then apply "cur" to the new link. Here's my code:

```
<li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.bankCssClass($data)" data-key="工商银行" data-code="ICBC-NET-B2C" class="bank_2">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class=""></a></li>
```

jQUERY :

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass('');
        $(this).addClass('cur');
    });
});
```

Comment: if you add a sample to your post like you did... you may should add it like an usable sample... in your sample there is no element with the class `cur`. So running this in a testcase would not bring up anything and causes "helpers" to guess if the answere/result is right :) (just as a hint)

Comment: You better add other neighbouring li elements too, it will help us to better uderstand what can be optimal for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('cur');
        $(this).addClass('cur');
    });
});
```

Hope it will work :)

[parent method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[siblings method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('li.blank-2 a').removeClass('cur');
        $(this).addClass('cur');
    });
});
```

If your other lis also have the class blank-2

Answer (score 0):

**removeClass(className)** takes the name of class you want to remove. So try this:

```
$('a').removeClass('cur');
```

Comment: OP sayed `I want the previous link's "cur" class to be removed` your source will remove all. So this is no solution

Comment: I point out why the OP's code isn't working at all. The OP should be able to go on from here on his own, judging on the code he already wrote.

Comment: But obviously he dont know `.parent()` and he still will deal with the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you could change yout HTML to something like this

HTML

```
<!-- add a parent class (if you dit not do already) You can give it a class like parent --> 
<ul class="parent">
    <!-- give you're child also a class (and one of them is active) -->
    <li><a href="" class="child active">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="child">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="child">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    // find you're specific group you want to click 
    $('a.child').click(function(event){
        // catch and stop the default action
        event.preventDefault();
        // find the specific parent (upstream the dom) (in this case ul with class parent)
        var $parent = $(this).closest("ul.parent");
        // search within your dom structure (downstream) for a child with a class that is active
        // and remove the class
        $parent.find("a.active").removeClass("active");
        // add the class to the clicked a 
        $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure out whats the solution for this . I might wanna share it out .

HTML :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: thirdPayBank" class="bank_list" style="height: 102px;">
                        <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="工商银行" data-code="ICBC" class="bank_2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a></li>

                         <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="农业银行" data-code="ABC" class="bank_3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a></li>
```

CSS :

```
.bank_list li a.cur {
            width: 198px;
            height: 48px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #f0bebe;
            background: url(../images/zijin_icon.png) no-repeat -897px -188px;
        }
```

jQUERY :

```
 $(".bank").click(function(){
            $(".bank").removeClass('bankcur')     
            $(this).addClass('bankcur')
    })
```

RESULT : 
[image]